# Need help with this question. A graph has K10 as a subgraph. What does this tell us about the size of a maximum matching?

Tags: graph-theory

Need help with this question.  A graph has K10 as a subgraph. What does this tell us about the size of a maximum matching? (Does it give us an upper bound? A lower bound? Or does it tell us nothing?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

- What is the size of maximum matching in $K_{10}$?
- Take any matching that does not match some two vertices of aforementioned $K_{10}$, is it maximal?
- Again: what does this tell you about the size of a maximum matching?
- As for the upper bound: consider a graph which is a disjoint union of $K_{10}$ and $2008$ copies of $K_2$, what is the size of a maximum matching in this graph?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Can you verify my thoughts to your questions-

A maximum matching in $K_{10}$ is $5$, this is also a maximal matching. Therefore, the lower bound would be $5$. 

I believe there is no upper bound. In the example given, each copy of $K_2$ would count as a matching so the maximum matching of the $K_{10}$ component and all of the $K_2$ components would be 2013.

Comment: @user2553807 Correct.